# Can a seekbar have multiple thumbs?

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to make a seekbar that has multiple thumbs. I want the second / third  thumbs to indicate certain section of the whole seekbar. For example :

---O--------V====V--------V======V-------

Here --- is seekbar, O is the first thumb, and V====V is a section, to show that a video file has some special scene in the section. I want the V to movable also.

Is there any way to make this function by only manipulating seekbar ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
private void updateSeekBarStyle(SeekBar seekBar) {
        int percentage = (int) ((seekBar.getProgress()/(float)seekBar.getMax())*100);
        if(percentage > 75) {
            seekBar.setThumb(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.seekbar_thumb_red));
        } else if (percentage > 50) {
            seekBar.setThumb(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.seekbar_thumb_blue));
        } else if (percentage > 25) {
            seekBar.setThumb(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.seekbar_thumb_green));
        }else{
            seekBar.setThumb(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.seekbar_thumb_default));
        }
        //seekBar.setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.seekbar_progress));
    }
```

You can call this method from onProgressChanged

```
 seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                     updateSeekBarStyle(seekBar);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
    
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
            });
```

Comment: Is this arbitrarily settable ? I mean, can I decide the progress value to setThumb without using onProgressChanged ?

Comment: onProgressChanged method is called when user manually changes the progress or when you update progress from video progress method with seekBar.setProgress (videoCurrentProgress). It's the same for you because you have to update progress for video. If you want to mark video sections then you have to create custom seekbar or use library like this https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar